# How to know if function is a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, summation

I created the formula $f: \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ $$f(n) = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^3 (2i+1)^2-2ki$$ Now Somebody else stated that we actually have:
$$f(n) = \frac{8n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3} + 2n(n+1) + 4n + 1$$
If you wouldve told me that my formula was actually a polynomial of third degree, I wouldve calculate small examples to find the values of a,b,c,d.

**Question:** How could I have seen beforehand that my formula was actualy a third degree polynomial? Or a polynomial at all? This is not something I think about when I see my $f$, so what are big indicators?

**Background:** The formula is actually the answer to this question: https://projecteuler.net/problem=28.

Comment: The fact that you are only summing a finite number of polynomials means the result will be a polynomial. To work out the degree is a bit more involved.

Comment: If $P(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, then $$S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n P(i)$$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$. Not at all unlike what happens when you integrate polynomials! The proof follows from for example Faulhaber's formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(n) = 1+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^3 (2i+1)^2-2ki=\\
1+\sum_{i=1}^n(4(2i+1)^2-12i)=\\
1+\sum_{i=1}^n(16i^2+4i+4)=\\
1+16\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+4\sum_{i=1}^ni+4\sum_{i=1}^n1$$

So you only need to know that $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2$ can be expressed as a polynomial of third degree, $\sum_{i=1}^ni$ as a polynomial of second degree and $\sum_{i=1}^n1=n$ is a first degree polynomial and $1$ is a constant.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) is something a bit more general, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The $ (2i+1)^2$ term under summation will give a third order polynomial. I don't know any general method but for this particular example, it works.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^3 (2i+1)^2-2ki=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^3 (2i+1)^2-\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^32ki=\sum_{i=1}^n(2i+1)^2-\sum_{i=1}^n12i$$

From $(2i+1)^2=4i^2+4i+1$ you get the formula
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(2i+1)^2=\frac{(2n-3)(n-1)(2n-1)}{3}$$ (*you know the formula for
$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n i$*).

Then you have $$\sum_{i=1}^n(2i+1)^2=\frac{4n^3+12n^2+11n-3}{3}-1$$ This is the part of third degree you are interested (the complete answer do not add terms of third degree).